# set 2 images in gridview onitemclick

Tags: android-gridview, onitemclicklistener, onitemclick

I am new to android and java world hardly 3 months working on it. Hence please help with me. I have gridview which display default images. My requirement is when user click on the item set product image for some time e.g. 2/3 seconds and again display default image. Please let me know how can I handle this. Sample code will be appreciated.

Currently I have following non working code which always show default image

```
        gridview.setOnItemClickListener(new OnItemClickListener() {
        public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View imgView,
                int position, long id) {

            ImageAdapter adapter = (ImageAdapter) parent.getAdapter();
            ImageView imageView = (ImageView) imgView;
            imageView.setImageResource(R.drawable.productImage);
                            Thread.sleep(1000);
            imageView.setImageResource(R.drawable.bg_default_card);
            }
        });
```

Answer (score 0):

I found the workaround. I create object of Runnable and set image to default image in run method

I put following code in onItemClick event. I create one class level variable for imageview e.g. imgView1 assign the clicked image to imgView1 onItemClick event

```
//create runable object
Runnable r1 = new Runnable() {
    public void run() {
        //check imageView1 not null            
        if (imgView1 != null) {                          
            //set image to default
            imgView1.setImageResource(R.drawable.bg_default_card);
    }
}
};
//call runnable after some interval
imgView1.postDelayed(r1, 500);
```

Thank you.